How to Describe Infinite Lines
I would like to create a script to shrink an object.
In doing so, I would like to run an infinite line (along XYZ or other axis) along the object in modal mode.
What kind of script would make this possible?
The preferred direction of the line is along the object's rotation.


GPU Module can do this. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

Thanks! I would like to know how to draw an "infinite line" with the GPU module.

Operator - Move object:
worked on blender 4.0

X: lock X axis
Y: lock Y axis
Z: lock Z axis
TAB: switch between local space and global space


import bpy, gpu
from bpy.props import BoolProperty
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_location_3d
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

INDICES = ((0, 1),)
SHADER = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')
AXIS_LEN = float(0xffff)
HANDLE = None

def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    try:
        local_space = self.local_space
    except:
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
        return

    if self.lock_axis == "NONE": return

    if self.lock_axis == "X":
        axis_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)
        coords = [Vector((-AXIS_LEN, 0, 0)), Vector((AXIS_LEN, 0, 0))]
    elif self.lock_axis == "Y":
        axis_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        coords = [Vector((0, -AXIS_LEN, 0)), Vector((0, AXIS_LEN, 0))]
    elif self.lock_axis == "Z":
        axis_color = (0, 0, 1, 1)
        coords = [Vector((0, 0, -AXIS_LEN)), Vector((0, 0, AXIS_LEN))]

    if local_space:
        loc, rot, sca = context.object.matrix_world.decompose()
        mat = Matrix.LocRotScale(loc, rot, None)
    else:
        mat = Matrix.Translation(context.object.location)

    coords[0] = mat @ coords[0]
    coords[1] = mat @ coords[1]

    batch = batch_for_shader(SHADER, 'LINES', {"pos": coords}, indices=INDICES)
    gpu.state.depth_test_set("LESS")
    SHADER.bind()
    SHADER.uniform_float("color", axis_color)
    batch.draw(SHADER)


class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_draw_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal View3D Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO", "GRAB_CURSOR", "BLOCKING"}

    local_space: BoolProperty(name="Local Space")

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            old_x, old_y = self.old_pos
            dx = event.mouse_region_x - old_x
            dy = event.mouse_region_y - old_y

            if abs(dx) > self.cursor_threshold or abs(dy) > self.cursor_threshold:
                self.old_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]
                return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

            region = context.region
            rv3d = context.region_data
            depth_location = context.object.location
            old_loc = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (old_x, old_y), depth_location)
            new_loc = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y), depth_location)
            offset = new_loc - old_loc

            if self.lock_axis == "X":
                offset[1] = 0.0
                offset[2] = 0.0
                if self.local_space:
                    offset = self.init_rotation @ offset
            elif self.lock_axis == "Y":
                offset[0] = 0.0
                offset[2] = 0.0
                if self.local_space:
                    offset = self.init_rotation @ offset
            elif self.lock_axis == "Z":
                offset[0] = 0.0
                offset[1] = 0.0
                if self.local_space:
                    offset = self.init_rotation @ offset

            context.object.location += offset
            self.old_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.location = self.init_location
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        elif event.value == 'PRESS':
            if event.type == "TAB": # change local/global space
                self.local_space = not self.local_space
            elif event.type == "X":
                self.lock_axis = "X"
            elif event.type == "Y":
                self.lock_axis = "Y"
            elif event.type == "Z":
                self.lock_axis = "Z"

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            ob = context.object
            if not ob:
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "Make a object active first")
                return {'CANCELLED'}
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            global HANDLE
            HANDLE = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

            loc, rot, sca = ob.matrix_world.decompose()
            self.init_location = loc
            self.init_rotation = rot
            self.old_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]
            self.lock_axis = "NONE"
            self.cursor_threshold = context.region.width // 2
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "TEST_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Test_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator(ModalDrawOperator.bl_idname, text="Modal Move Operator")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Thank you for even considering Guroval! You are fantastic.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/319389/89484
Based on Mr. XY's excellent answer, I have completed my original goal,
I have completed a Script that allows me to freely control the reduction of XYZ during the modal.
Thank you very much.

bl_info = {
    "name": "Axis Scaling",
    "author": "KSYN, XY",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (4, 1, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > Item",
    "description": "Allows scaling of objects along X, Y, and Z axes in a modal operator",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/319371/89484",
    "category": "Object",
}


import bpy, gpu, bmesh

from bpy.props import BoolProperty
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_location_3d
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

INDICES = ((0, 1),)
SHADER = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')
AXIS_LEN = float(0xffff)
HANDLE = None

def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    try:
        local_space = self.local_space
    except:
        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
        return

    axes = {'X': ((1, 0, 0, 1), [Vector((-AXIS_LEN, 0, 0)), Vector((AXIS_LEN, 0, 0))]),
            'Y': ((0, 1, 0, 1), [Vector((0, -AXIS_LEN, 0)), Vector((0, AXIS_LEN, 0))]),
            'Z': ((0, 0, 1, 1), [Vector((0, 0, -AXIS_LEN)), Vector((0, 0, AXIS_LEN))])}

    if local_space:
        loc, rot, sca = context.object.matrix_world.decompose()
        mat = Matrix.LocRotScale(loc, rot, None)
    else:
        mat = Matrix.Translation(context.object.location)

    for axis in self.lock_axes:
        axis_color, coords = axes[axis]
        coords[0] = mat @ coords[0]
        coords[1] = mat @ coords[1]
        
        batch = batch_for_shader(SHADER, 'LINES', {"pos": coords}, indices=INDICES)
        gpu.state.depth_test_set("LESS")
        SHADER.bind()
        SHADER.uniform_float("color", axis_color)
        batch.draw(SHADER)


import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector

def scale_mesh_global(obj, direction, factor):
    
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        raise ValueError(f"Object {obj.name} is not a mesh.")
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    
    world_matrix = obj.matrix_world
    world_matrix_inv = world_matrix.inverted()
    
    scale_vector = Vector((1, 1, 1))
    direction = direction.upper()
    if direction == 'X':
        scale_vector.x = factor
    elif direction == 'Y':
        scale_vector.y = factor
    elif direction == 'Z':
        scale_vector.z = factor
    else:
        raise ValueError("Direction must be 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'.")
    
    obj_location = obj.location
    
    for vert in bm.verts:
        global_coord = world_matrix @ vert.co
        offset_coord = global_coord - obj_location
        scaled_offset_coord = offset_coord * scale_vector
        scaled_global_coord = scaled_offset_coord + obj_location
        vert.co = world_matrix_inv @ scaled_global_coord
    
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

class AxisScalingOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.axis_scaling_operator"
    bl_label = "Axis Scaling Operator"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO", "GRAB_CURSOR", "BLOCKING"}

    local_space: BoolProperty(name="Local Space",default=True) # type: ignore

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type in {'MIDDLEMOUSE','WHEELDOWNMOUSE','WHEELUPMOUSE', 'NUMPAD_1', 'NUMPAD_2', 'NUMPAD_3', 'NUMPAD_4', 'NUMPAD_5', 'NUMPAD_6', 'NUMPAD_7', 'NUMPAD_8', 'NUMPAD_9'} or (event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE' and event.ctrl):
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            old_x, old_y = self.old_pos
            dy = event.mouse_region_y - old_y

            if abs(dy) > self.cursor_threshold:
                self.old_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]
                return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

            scale_factor = 1.0 + (dy * 0.01)

            for axis in self.lock_axes:
                
                if not self.local_space:
      
                    scale_mesh_global(context.object, axis, scale_factor)
                   
                else:
                    if axis == "X":
                        context.object.scale[0] *= scale_factor
                    elif axis == "Y":
                        context.object.scale[1] *= scale_factor
                    elif axis == "Z":
                        context.object.scale[2] *= scale_factor

            self.old_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
            context.area.header_text_set(None)
            context.workspace.status_text_set(None)
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.scale = self.init_scale
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(HANDLE, 'WINDOW')
            context.area.header_text_set(None)
            context.workspace.status_text_set(None)
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        elif event.type == 'P' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective = (
                'ORTHO' if context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective == 'PERSP' else 'PERSP'
            )
        elif event.value == 'PRESS':
            if event.type == "TAB":  # change local/global space
                self.local_space = not self.local_space
            elif event.type in {"X", "Y", "Z"}:
                if event.type in self.lock_axes:
                    self.lock_axes.remove(event.type)
                else:
                    self.lock_axes.add(event.type)

        header_message = f"Scaling on axes: {', '.join(self.lock_axes)} | Local Space: {self.local_space} | Perspective: {context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective}"
        context.area.header_text_set(header_message)
        
        status_message = "Use X, Y, Z to toggle axis scaling. Use TAB to toggle local/global space. Press P to toggle perspective. LMB to confirm, RMB or ESC to cancel."
        context.workspace.status_text_set(status_message)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            ob = context.object
            if not ob:
                self.report({'WARNING'}, "Make an object active first")
                return {'CANCELLED'}
            # the arguments we pass to the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            global HANDLE
            HANDLE = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

            loc, rot, sca = ob.matrix_world.decompose()
            self.init_scale = sca.copy()
            self.old_pos = [event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y]
            self.lock_axes = set()
            self.cursor_threshold = context.region.width // 2
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            context.area.header_text_set("Modal Scale Operator Active")
            status_message = "Use X, Y, Z to toggle axis scaling. Use TAB to toggle local/global space. Press P to toggle perspective. LMB to confirm, RMB or ESC to cancel."
            context.workspace.status_text_set(status_message)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

class TransformAxisPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "AXIS_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Axis Scale Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator(AxisScalingOperator.bl_idname, text="Axis Scaling")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AxisScalingOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TransformAxisPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AxisScalingOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TransformAxisPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

